# How do I develop for STM32 discovery on Linux?

Tags: linux, stm32, development, development-tools

I have an STM32 discovery board and would like to be able to program it on Linux.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I installed Codesourcery on LinuxhUbuntu and little bit stacked: PATH is ok but the program does not appear on dasboard or software centre. Maybe it is the Ubuntu I would change somehow but do not know how.
If you have an idea, please write.
Thank you.
Tom

Comment: @TomRitzmann PeterJ is right, please don't use answers to ask questions. Moreover, software problems are off-topic here, SuperUser is the right place.

Comment: The online book The Embedded Rust Book at URL https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/intro/index.html uses the STM32 Discovery board in its tutorials. See also the GitHub at https://github.com/rust-embedded/discovery

Comment: See also ST documentation, webinars, and learning resources at https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/support/learning/recorded-webinars.html

Answer (score 15):

An easy way to program and debug the STM32 Discovery board (or any STM32 using an ST-Link programmer) is to use the 'stlink' project https://github.com/texane/stlink (however OpenOCD seems popular too)

ST Nucleo boards also appear as a USB flash device, so don't even need `stlink` - just copy the file over to them.

There are some good pages on how to develop for STM32 discovery on Linux, such as http://gpio.kaltpost.de/?page_id=131 and  http://torrentula.to.funpic.de/2012/03/22/setting-up-the-stm32f4-arm-development-toolchain/ and http://jethomson.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/getting-started-with-the-stm32f4discovery-in-linux/

However I found the last link the most useful. It shows how to build ST's STM32 projects as-is - The only change is to add his Makefile, which seems like a perfect solution.

On recent versions of Ubuntu, there is a package you can install which contains an ARM compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi
```

Note that the processors are all a bit different. STM32F0..4 will all need different compiler flags, and the linker script will be slightly different for each (although only really because of the changed RAM and Flash sizes).

Edit: if you want to get started *really quickly* you could also look at http://www.espruino.com. It's a JavaScript interpreter that runs on the STM32 itself, so once you've got 'stlink' installed so you can flash to the board you can just download an image from that site, flash it on, and then connect with a terminal application and start programming.

Comment: Here is a list of supported STM32x Discovery boards by OpenOCD: https://github.com/openrisc/openOCD/tree/master/tcl/board (search for "discovery" using your browser)

Answer (score 12):

If You are more into text editors and Makefiles instead of using a GUI, you could do:

- Install a toolchain providing arm-none-eabi-gcc. On Archlinux, you would need community/arm-none-eabi-binutils, arm-none-eabi-gcc and arm-none-eabi-newlib (and arm-none-eabi-gdb if you want to debug) all from the community repo, or https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded (Which can be found in Archlinux' AUR as gcc-arm-none-eabi-bin).
- Decide, if and what library you want to use to access the hardware. From the top of my head, there are three common options:

  1. None. You write everything from scratch. Not recommendable for beginners.
  2. [STM32Cube](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF259243): A C lib provided by ST itself.
  3. [Libopencm3](http://libopencm3.org/wiki/Main_Page): An open source lib supporting quite many cortex-m cores by different vendors.
  4. [STM32PLUS](http://andybrown.me.uk/2011/12/28/stm32plus-a-c-library-for-stm32-development): A C++ lib. However, I cannot say much more about it because I haven't tested it.
- Create or copy your first project.

  1. Without a lib, write your own makefile, linker script, startup code and get a simple makefile running. Good luck ;)
  2. With STM32Cube: Download and install [STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF259242). Once unzipped the *.exe file is actually just a java file and you can run it using "java -jar filename.exe". The installation needs sudo. When done, create a project and generate the code for "Truestudio". That should give you a starting point with a linker script, startup code, some trivial main-function (and a makefile if I remember correctly). Actually, even if you don't use the STM32Cube lib, the STM32CubeMX is great for calculating the values for the clock tree and validating if you can configure the chip the way you think.
  3. With libopencm3: Get the [libopencm3 examples](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3-examples), find an example matching your board and use this as a starting point. The examples should be ready to run. Just type "make". Then use that example as a starting point for your own development.
  4. With STM32Plus: I don't know. Sorry.
- Get your project to the board. Either use

  1. The serial bootloader: [stm32flash](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stm32flash) works great.
  2. The debug port: You can use [openocd](http://openocd.org) to talk to the debugging adaptor provided on the board. Openocd is great, but documentation is not always the best. When in doubt, join the openocd irc channel. The people there are really nice.
- Code in a text editor and use command line tools. [This tutorial](http://fun-tech.se/stm32/index.php) will provide lots of tips.

Enjoy

Answer (score 6):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [GCC](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/), and [OpenOCD](http://openocd.sourceforge.net/) is one toolchain.  It's recommended by [EMCU-IT](http://www.emcu.it/STM32/What_should_I_use_to_develop_on_STM32/What_should_I_use_to_develop_on_STM32.html#LINUX_tools) and there's additional information [here](http://www.stf12.org/developers/ODeV.html). Those pages also recommend using an RTOS like [FreeRTOS.org](http://www.freertos.org/), but that's up to you.

And for help with compiling the STM32 examples in Linux [go here](http://snowcap.fi/blog/2011/11/27/compiling-stm32-examples-in-linux/).  That link points to a makefile for the examples which can be invoked with

```
git clone git://github.com/snowcap-electronics/stm32-examples.git
cd stm32-examples
wget http://www.st.com/internet/com/SOFTWARE_RESOURCES/SW_COMPONENT/FIRMWARE/stm32_f105-07_f2xx_usb-host-device_lib.zip
unzip stm32_f105-07_f2xx_usb-host-device_lib.zip
```

A couple minor code fixes are also documented, but most of the project should work with

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-eabi-
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen those links before. I'm amazed there isn't a more definitive guide somewhere though as different discovery boards have subtly different build flags.

Comment: Yeah, ST made a very cheap board and gave them away, thousands of them, and the STM32 itself is an awesome chip, all the way up to F4, but programming them is a huge pain in the butt. Their drivers are incredibly poorly documented, and not named well, and finding a IDE and tool chain that play well together for free is not too easy.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with https://github.com/JorgeAparicio/bareCortexM (see also the linked blog posts). I'm floored that I can simply single-step through the code or browse the device memory instead of inserting debugging statements in my code or guessing what is going on inside the chip.

The bareCortexM project is an Eclipse template for developing with the Cortex M series, especially STM32, in C++ without an OS. It is configured to use openocd, gcc, and has scripts to flash and debug to several targets including some of the discovery boards. By following the instructions and installing the recommended Eclipse plugins I was able to use my STM32VLDISCOVERY on Ubuntu.

As recommended I've combined the eclipse template with the same author's libstm32pp C++ template library for STM32 hardware. libstm32pp provides a surprisingly complete replacement for CMSIS and the often criticized STM32 drivers with a programming model that lets you say things like `PB10::setMode(gpio::cr::GP_OPEN_DRAIN_2MHZ)` and `PINB::setLow()` or `PINB::setHigh()` all mostly compiled inline due to the C++ templates. The setup is very nice.

Comment: I no longer recommend the unmaintained bareCortexM; check out stm32plus at http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/

Comment: The problem with such device drivers is that they are inefficient. For proper high speed device drivers that do not waste cpu cycles you need an rtos underneath so you can do proper scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be useful for someone: my [short article](http://habrahabr.ru/post/161863/) (on russian) and [simple project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ircontroller/). All in linux and without unnecessary things like eclipse.

Libraries was taken from ST website, makefile — from one of many GPL examples in internet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small but innovative template project for the quick start using STM32F0 Discovery board under Linux or any other OS:

https://github.com/dobromyslov/stm32f0-chibios-template

Note that the project uses ChibiOS - a free and open source real time operating system so it's not exactly a bare bone implementation from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I use vim and arm-none-eabi-gcc along with all the usual linux dev tools. Linux is in my opinion superior dev environment for embedded work by far. For debugging I use stlink and arm-none-eabi-gdb.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [platformio](https://platformio.org/platforms/ststm32). If you're at all comfortable with the command-line, you'll find that platformio eases the development process considerably. `pio init` can be used to set up a project. `pio run` leverages the toolchain to compile. `pio run --target upload` sends the code to the device. Platformio takes care of downloading the toolchain components, libraries, etc. as needed.