# STM32L-Discovery programming on Linux with Eclipse

Tags: stm32, linux, eclipse, stm32l

my problem is following.

How to configure Eclipse + ARM in order to code for this microcontroller?
I installed Eclipse and ARM plugin for it but I can't understand what to do after that :(

Comment: Have you installed the GNU toolchain?

Comment: I installed ARM Plugin and Codesourcery

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of related links in this post: [click here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32991/how-do-i-develop-for-stm32-discovery-on-linux?rq=1)

Not all linux specific, but I think it would be very useful reading to set up your software environment as well for understanding what you are doing when doing it.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://fun-tech.se/stm32/gcc/index.php) looks like a good place to start. It covers getting hold of the right compiler (or building it from source if you prefer) and getting started with the "hello world" of the microcontroller world, inevitably called "blinky" because it just blinks a LED to show the program is working.

Comment: I installed Codesourcery and now I don't know what to do

Comment: Load a project and try to compile it.